# How to export and read json output from neo4j cypher queries?

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

After running cypher query on neo4j, I can export/download the result as json or csv format. However, as I tried to import that into python, I found error as the json and csv are not formatted properly. Can someone please  help with importing into json? Thank you.

```
with open(file_path, "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 2
      1 with open(file_path, "r") as file:
----> 2     data = json.load(file)
```

Comment: can you share the code that exported the results?

Comment: It's not about the export, after running any query in neo4j-browser, you can go to table-view. There is a download button at the right side of the query input text. Then, I downloaded the json. That I tried to import using json.load. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The exported file from neo4j browser is using a different encoding. Please use "utf-8-sig" as encoding.

```
import json
file_path = 'test_records.json' 
with open(file_path, "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)
```

Sample output:

```
[{'n': {'identity': 45, 'labels': ['Person'], 'properties': {'name': 'Bob'}}}, {'n': {'identity': 49, 'labels': ['Person'], 'properties': {'name': 'Alice'}}}, {'n': {'identity': 52, 'labels': ['Person'], 'properties': {'name': 'Bob'}}}, {'n': {'identity': 53, 'labels': ['Person'], 'properties': {'name': 'Alice'}}}]
```

Below are my notebook and python versions:

```
The version of the notebook server is: 6.5.4
The server is running on this version of Python:
Python 3.9.6 (default, Oct 18 2022, 12:41:40) 
[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and willingness to help. Unfortunately, didn't work. Got a new problem, <<SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 11 column 137 of the JSON data>> I tried opening the file in a browser, have got same error!

Comment: please share your file to me. We are not seated together in the office. I don't even see you. LOLZ